# Noob Question - Export Model From Blender then Animate with Python

Tags: python, rendering, animation, scripting

I'm new to Blender and 3D model stuff in general. I am attempting to build a python application that will have a 3d model of a face talk. I have a rigged face model that I have been working with in Blender, and my idea was to export it in a file format that would allow me to manipulate and move the rigged points on the face programmatically.

That way, I could make a facial position for every phoneme and interpolate between them to animate the face to "say" arbitrary sentences.

It's been a difficult process trying to ask questions to google, since I don't have the vocabulary to express the things that I want, so I thought I'd try asking humans on here:

Is what i'm trying to do possible?

What file format would meet the qualifications I'm looking for? I'm currently thinking that a .dae Collada file seems to fit the bill, though i'm unsure if i'm able to animate something while it is being rendered.

Thanks!

Comment: So you basically want a Python 3D engine (since exporting from Blender implies not using Blender), something like Ogre. If you're looking for a competitive 3D engine then you probably have to resign from Python and use e.g. Unity (C#) which support shape keys (it's called blendshapes there). https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlendShapes.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off leaving the model in blender. Blender has its own API, which I have considered using for just such a purpose (but I haven’t felt motivated to do the phoenome research neccesary). You could save mouth positions as poses, and then apply them with Python and set keyframes at the desired places.

Comment: Right, It seems most resources connecting python with Blender revolve around the API. The problem for me is, ultimately, what i'm working on needs to run on a raspberry pi or something similar. Additionally it needs to run as a standalone app. I'm not familiar w/ the API, but can it do those things?

Comment: No, the api cannot export. This actually means the question is not really for this site. This has to do with what you should do in blender to accomplish a how outside of it.